# Dropbox's "Manage backup" is missing on my new Mac

Tags: backup, dropbox, apple-silicon

I used to use Dropbox to backup my Desktop/Documents/Downloads, and it worked out fine on my old Mac.

However, I recently bought a new Macbook with the M1 chip. When I go to Dropbox -> preference -> backups, the "Manage backup" tab is missing. When I log in to my Dropbox account under the [security tab](https://www.dropbox.com/account/security), I can see my new Mac's name (M1) appear under the Device name. Can someone help me with how to enable "Manage backup" on my new Mac?

I notice that the Desktop and Downloads folders are "connected" to my old Mac. If I add or delete some files on either my old or my new Mac, the other Mac will perform the same modification. However, the Documents folder is not connected to my old Mac.

Comment: Have you contacted Dropbox support, or looked at their website?

Comment: @IconDaemon Yes. I asked the same question on Dropbox community forum, but so far no people replied to me.

Comment: Yoiu seem to say opposite things 1) If I add or delete some files on either my old or my new Mac, the other Mac will perform the same modification 2) he Documents folder is not connected to my old Mac - If 2 how do you see the chnaged document on your old Mac

Comment: @mmmmmm The Desktop and Downloads folders are connected with my old Mac, but the Documents folder is not. The Documents folder of my old Mac is backed up by Dropbox, but that in my new Mac is not.